# How to display events when clicking a date on calendar

Tags: ios, swift, events, calendar

I am using [JTAppleCalendar](https://github.com/patchthecode/JTAppleCalendar) for an app where users will be able to schedule events/reminders on the calendar.
I am having a difficult time trying to get this functionality to get built. Ideally, when a user clicks on a certain date on the calendar, an area at the bottom of the calendar would show the event details pertaining to that day.

I am completely clueless as to where i would even begin.

Answer (score 2):

If I understood correctly, you want to respond to cell selection events.

It's similar to how UICollectionView/TableView works: You need to implement the delegate which in this case is called [`JTAppleCalendarViewDelegate`](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/JTAppleCalendar/7.0.4/Protocols/JTAppleCalendarViewDelegate.html). The method you are looking for is `calendar(_:didSelectDate:cell:cellState:)` which *Tells the delegate that a date-cell with a specified date was selected*.

```
class CalendarViewController: JTAppleCalendarViewDelegate {

    func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        calendarView.delegate = self
    }

    func calendar(_ calendar: JTAppleCalendarView, didSelectDate date: Date, cell: JTAppleCell?, cellState: CellState) {
        // Do something.
    }

}
```